# i want to do the animation on Image view to change width of the Image view as below

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do animation on imageview as below
[image: First image]

[image: Second Image]

[image: third Image]

Need to animate to like this.

Comment: what is the increment rate of your image length? i mean is that only 3 steps?

Comment: Whenever i enter in this activity then it will take max value as reference i.e. 6085 and then it animate all image view of colors by 0 to its respective percentage value of max value ..and increment rate would as in like gradual an smooth increase to is respective max value from 0.

Comment: hi vnShetty u have any idea how can i do it ....Adavance thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution 
ScaleAnimation solved the issue

```
int maxValue = 6085;
final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
linearLayout1 =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.iv1);linearLayout2 =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.iv2);

linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(calculatePercentage(maxValue,3853),(int) (20 * scale + 0.5f)));
        linearLayout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(calculatePercentage(maxValue,3026), (int) (20 * scale + 0.5f)));

ScaleAnimation anim1 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        ScaleAnimation anim2 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f);
            anim1.setDuration(7000);
            anim2.setDuration(7000);
           linearLayout1.startAnimation(anim1);
           linearLayout2.startAnimation(anim2);
```

and code for calculate percentage

```
public int calculatePercentage(int maxValue,int value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "maxValue  :  "+maxValue);
        Log.v(TAG, "Value  :  "+value);
        float division =(float)(value)/(float)maxValue;
        int percenatgeValue =(int) (division*100);
        Log.v(TAG, "percenatgeValue  :  "+percenatgeValue);
        return percenatgeValue;
    }
```